# Mega dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm using a [Mega Dropdown menu](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/), when I click an option, the `href` tag is executed but the menu is kept open. I am forced to move the mouse away from the menu to close it.  How can I close the menu after a user click or Selection.  This is a menu based on pure CSS. I think I am missing some jQuery or JavaScript to take care of the event. Would you help?

Comment: You'd better include some code in your question so we can assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after using your jsfiddle code I think you'll need to use some jQuery along these lines:

```
$("ul.greybox").find("a").each(function() {
    //$(this).attr("href", "#"); Just for testing
    $(this).click(function() {$(".dropdown_3columns").attr('style', 'display:none');});
});
```

This basically, sets the style of the dropdown div `.dropdown_3columns` to `display:none` when the user clicks on one of the items in that dropdown.

Check it working here - [http://jsfiddle.net/RpfYa/](http://jsfiddle.net/RpfYa/1/)

Comment: Hi Alex, please find below the code and also the CSS code.  The problem is that when I click an option, it gets executed but the MEGA is not closed. I need to move the cursor away from the MEGA so It can close.  Thanks!   --- NOTE: I just have 355 character left. No space for the code or CSS. How can I send them to you?

Comment: <%@ Language=VBScript %>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js2011/Megamenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>ADMIN</title>
<link href="js2011/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="js2011/AeroWindow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2011/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2011/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js2011/hoverIntent.js"></script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js2011/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2011/jquery-AeroWindow.min.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 6]><style>body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}#menu li .drop {background:url("js2011/img/drop.gif") no-repeat right 8px; </style><![endif]-->
<style> 
      body {
        background: #09368b url(win7-desktop-bg.jpg);
      }
</style>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   function addMenu(){
        $(this).addClass("hovering");
        }
   function removeMenu(){
        $(this).removeClass("hovering");
        }
    var menuConfig = {
         interval: 500,
         sensitivity: 4,
         over: addMenu,
         timeout: 500,
         out: removeMenu
    };   
$("li.menu").hoverIntent(menuConfig)
</script>
</head> <body>
<div id="AeroWindowLinks"> <!--START AERO -->
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Reports</a><!-- Begin 3 columns Item -->

Comment: </li><!-- End 3 columns Item -->
    <li class="drop"><a href="#" class="drop">Security</a><!-- Begin 3 columns Item --> 
        <div class="dropdown_3columns align_left" style="font-size: 9px;" style="background-image:url(images/info_security.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:left top;"><!-- Begin 3 columns container -->         
            <div class="col_3">
                <h2>TEST ACCESS CONTROL</h2>
            </div>           
            <div class="col_1"> 
                <ul class="greybox">

Comment: <li><a href="http://www.google.co.ve/">Set user as System Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.ve/">Set user as Dep. Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Set user as Approver and Dep. Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Set user as Approver and System Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reset user access to Regular only</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reset user access to Approver only</a></li>
                </ul>   
    
            </div>

Comment: <div class="col_1">
                <ul class="greybox">
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.ve/">List current System Administratorsr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.co.ve/">List current Department Administratorsr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List current Other Administratorsr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List current regular Approvers</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>

Comment: </li><!-- End 3 columns Item -->   
</ul>
</div> <!--END AERO -->
<%
function ShowTitle( s, line)
'Just treat Title in a different way
dim oS, oI, oL, newS
s =Trim(s)
s = vbcrlf & replace(s,";",vbcrlf) & vbcrlf if line = 9 then
     s = ucase( s )  &  vbcrlf &  "UNDER REVISION!"
     ShowTitle = s
  elseif line > 0 then
     ShowTitle = s
  else 
     ShowTitle = s 
end if

Comment: end function
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Global Settings  
        var ShowTaskbar = true;
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ****************** PLease let me know if should send you the CSS using same approach.   ***************************************   THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: HERE one sample with the correct behavior:  http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml

Comment: WTF! like I said, used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Code it up in there, that'll give us something to work with.

Comment: Someone with comment deleting rights, please remove all the above comments except mine... ta

Comment: Sorry Alex for the inconvenience... I just register, but not access for that.

Comment: Just go to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) (no need to register) and paste all the code you pasted here, into there.

Comment: Alex, do not understand. I just did and put Javascript into a box and the rest on HTML.  What is the idea?

Comment: Paste the URL here so we can see it.

Comment: Alex, highly thank you for your effort.  I did some testing and your code does close the DROPDOWN NODE when I click an option, however, after that if I HOVER the sane DROPDOWN NODE, the menu doesn't show the DROPDOWN anymore.  I thought it was IE, but then I tried GOOGLE CHROME and got same problem. I believe, some JQUERY research on my own is in order. You did more than I expected. Any final recommendation?

Comment: I saw that so updated my answer example on jsfiddle. Check that. If it doesn't work I'll check when I'm at my Pc, on my phone at the mo.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo Aguilera, Yeah I had updated my answer check it out - [http://jsfiddle.net/RpfYa/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/RpfYa/1/).

Comment: Alex, ...it works. Excellent job.   Tank you for your time and the learning opportunity.

Comment: With all due respect, God bless you!

Comment: Please click on the tick to the left hand side of my answer. That's what to do if the answer give fixed the question. This is a fundamental part of stackoverflow, thanks